# How ro resolve this (Discord) SQLite error

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, discord, discord.js

I am a discord bot developer and I used JSON files as a database until it got corrupted. I went on the discord guide and they told me to switch to SQLite. I did switch but my code is throwing an error that I am trying to fix in the last 3 days. This is the error:

> (node:16500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near ")": syntax error
>   (node:16500) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
>   the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.*

The following is my code. People told me I'm missing some `')' or '}'` but I can not find anything.

```
    const sqlite = require('sqlite');
    client.sql = sqlite;
    client.sql.open('database.sqlite')
    client.sql.get(`SELECT * FROM settings WHERE guildid =                                                         
    "${message.guild.id}"`).then(row => {
    if(!row) {
        client.sql.run(`INSERT INTO settings (guildid, prefix, 
        lang, color, admin, mod, user, autor, channel) VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)`, [message.author.id, 
        '!', 'en', '#ffffff', 'admin', 'mod', 'false', 
        'false', 'false'])
        client.gprefix = '!';
    } else {
        client.gprefix = row.prefix;
    }
}).catch(() => {
    client.sql.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings 
    (guildid text UNIQUE, prefix text NOT NULL, lang text NOT 
    NULL, color text NOT NULL, admin text NOT NULL, mod text 
    NOT NULL, user text NOT NULL, autor text NOT NULL, channel 
    text NOT NULL`)
    client.sql.run(`INSERT INTO settings (guildid, prefix, 
    lang, color, admin, mod, user, autor, channel) VALUES (?, 
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)`, [message.author.id, '!', 'en', 
    '#ffffff', 'ad`enter code here`min', 'mod', 'false', 
    'false', 'false'])
        client.gprefix = '!';
})
```

**THIS POST IS FIXED BECAUSE OF Ilja Everilä THANK YOU!**

Comment: At least your CREATE TABLE statement is lacking a closing bracket, and there's an extra comma in the VALUES clause value list in one of your INSERT statements.

Comment: So I closed it but still having one of the 2 errors:
(node:16500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near ")": syntax error
(node:16500) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Fix the INSERT(s) as well. You should also fix this posts formatting. Please begin lines in a code block with 4 spaces. As a shortcut you should be able to select the code and press ctrl-k.